# Select element by name in jquery

Tags: jquery, select

Helo, i cant select element, can you help me?

After 
`var string = $('input[value="' + min + '"]').prop('name');`

I have `string = ObjectSize[2]`;

I need make this `$('input[name=' + string + ']').remove();`, but its not working.

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input:text[name=ObjectSize[2]]
```

Help me, please. Thank you

Comment: Add console.log(string) to your code and paste output somewhere. Need to see what its inside that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding double quotes in name:

```
$('input[name="' + string + '"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are getting object of more than 1 element. 
Try this code:

```
$('input[type="text"][name="' + string[0] + '"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

If `string` variable is an object (you found 2 elements with your selector). You cannot use object in `$('input[name=' + string + ']').remove();`

You need to check first if its an object:

```
if(typeof string === 'object') {
    $('input[name="' + string[Object.keys(string)[0]] + '"]').remove();
}
else 
    $('input[name="' + string + '"]').remove();
```